# How can i create a custom UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to know how can i create a custom UIButton with UILabel inside like this [image]

Comment: From the picture you added, I'm having some difficulty understanding the custom functionality that you are looking for in your custom UIButton. What do you want? Custom colors, font, or an image? Because all of those can be achieved without subclassing UIButton.

Comment: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Comment: I want to add 7 UILabel with their values ​​to the right as above and the container to be with this style?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on CIMGF [Fun with UIButtons and core animation layers](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/)

Alternatively: [IphoneDevelopment: Programmatic gradient buttons](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/programmatic-gradient-buttons.html)

You basically just create a subclass of your UIButton to implement **custom drawing**.
Then you can do whatever you want. These 2 tutorials shoudl be helpful in creating the style you want, remember that you can also use images if you don't want to fiddle with the drawing code too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
int i=0;
UIButton *customButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

//Set the height of your button, that will depend on how much text you will be putting
//inside
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(3,40,315,130)];

for(i=0; i<7; i++){
    //Their position will change depending on which label you are adding
    UILabel *leftLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5+(17*i), 150, 12)];
    UILabel *rightLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 5+(17*i), 150, 12)];

    //Set the text for each label
    [leftLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Left %d",i+1]];
    [rightLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Right %d",i+1]];

    //Set the backgroudn as clear to be able to see the background of your button
    [leftLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [rightLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //Add those labels
    [customButton addSubview:leftLabel];
    [customButton addSubview:rightLabel];

    //Do your memory management 
    [leftLabel release];
    [rightLabel release];
}
```

The CIMGF link will work for your style needs.